# JMeter groovy: how to get attributes value from json with attributes starting with a number

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I do have the following string which I parse with the JsonSlurper() to json.

```
{"id":"1111","fields":{"2_attribute":"111111","3_attribute":"11122222","4_attribute":"1111222211"}
```

I'm using in a JSR223 PreProcessor groovy script to get attribute "2_attribute" value with the following code `log.info("attribute2 :" + json2.fields.2_attribute);` and getting the following exception:

```
2022-06-01 13:18:25,491 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor2
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script197.groovy: 24: Number ending with underscores is invalid @ line 24, column 50 @ line 24, column 50.
   age_type_id:" + json2.fields.2_attribute
```

How could I manage to get the value?
attribute naming cannot change.

Thank you.

Comment: json2.fields.’2_attribute’ or json2.fields[‘2_attribute’]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to surround this `2_attribute` with quotation marks as in Groovy object names cannot start with a number.

```
def theValueIamLookingFor = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).fields."2_attribute"
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Syntax](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)